# Como podria mostrar estos if en un ciclo lo mas eficiente posible

Tags: java, condiciones, bucles, optimización, diseño-de-clases

No se como mostrar estos *if* en un ciclo, no se me ocurre nada. Ayuda solamente hacer un `for (i==0 ; i<4 ; i++)`, pero ahí no se que como hacerle, ignorar el método *IngresarJugador*.

```
class CentroVideoJuegos {
    
    private int IngresosTotales;
    private Estacion estacion1;
    private Estacion estacion2;
    private Estacion estacion3;
    private Estacion estacion4;
    
    private Estacion buscarEstacionPoridEstacion(int idEstacion){
        if (idEstacion==1) {
            return estacion1;
        }
         if (idEstacion==2) {
            return estacion2;
        }
          if (idEstacion==3) {
            return estacion3;
        }
           if (idEstacion==4) {
            return estacion4;
        }
        return null;
        
        /*for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            
        }
*/
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de tener una variable por cada Estacion puedes usar un HashMap y guardarlas ahí. Luego para recuperarlas solo usas el método `get()` con el idEstacion. Si no existe entonces retorna null, agrego ejemplo completo:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Test {
    
    private HashMap<Integer,Estacion> estaciones = new HashMap<Integer,Estacion>();
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        Test t = new Test();
        
        t.agregarEstaciones();
        
        System.out.println(t.buscarEstacionPorId(1).id);
        
      
    }
    
    private void agregarEstaciones(){
        
        Estacion estacion = new Estacion();
        estacion.id = 1;
        estaciones.put(estacion.id, estacion);
        
        estacion = new Estacion();
        estacion.id = 2;
        estaciones.put(estacion.id, estacion);
        
        estacion = new Estacion();
        estacion.id = 3;
        estaciones.put(estacion.id, estacion);
        
    }
    
    private Estacion buscarEstacionPorId(int idEstacion){
        return estaciones.get(idEstacion);
    }
    
    class Estacion{
        public int id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues validas contra el valor de `i` en cada iteración

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (idEstacion == i+1) {
                  //alguna cosa
            }    
        }
```

Comment: gracias crack :v

Comment: Con gusto. Recuerda además que puedes jugar con el intervalo del for como quieras. Yo podría hacer `for(int i = 1; i == 4; i++)`

Comment: oye pero como hago para retornarle al idEstacion su respectiva estacion ejm id= 4 debe retornar la estacion4 como hago?